# How to connect two computers on the same local network externally with Python sockets?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, network-programming, ipv6

I'm currently able to connect a client computer to two servers on my local network (using Python sockets), but because I'm trying to emulate an external networking set-up, I'd like the client to access the machines externally, i.e. for the data to be routed over the internet as opposed to locally and directly. (This is for research purposes, so it's intentionally inefficient.)

Would using a machine's IPv6 address as the host be sufficient, or would the router recognize the IPv6 address as internal and just bounce it back as opposed to first sending it to some external node?

Answer (score 1):

> or would the router recognize the IPv6 address as internal and just bounce it back as opposed to first sending it to some external node?

Yes

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a source of more information on this topic/answer? Sorry to ask, but I googled around but only found general information on routers and IPv6 without addressing this specific issue.

Comment: Routing always takes the shortest path, so if you communicate to something on your local network it will stay local. The only way to communicate over the internet is to have two different uplinks.

Answer (score 1):

If the client has at least two interfaces, you can assign one interface for local networking and the other one for Internet connection.
In addition, you can also try to use virtual interfaces + IP tunnel for the Internet connection.